# Verilog deterministic behavior

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is following code deterministic? i.e Can it trigger error1 or error2? Is there a recommended way for generating clk2 (same as clk3)

```
module Test();
    reg         clk1;
    reg         clk2;
    reg         clk3;
    reg         reset;

    initial
    begin
        clk1 <= 0;
        forever
        begin
            #100;
            clk1 <= ~clk1; // 2x freq of clk2/clk3
        end
    end

    always @(posedge clk1)
    begin
        if(reset)   clk2 <= 0;
        else        clk2 <= ~clk2;
    end

    initial
    begin
        clk3 <= 0;
        #300;
        forever
        begin
            #200;
            clk3 <= ~clk3;
        end
    end

    initial
    begin
        reset <= 1;
        #500;
        reset <= 0;
        #100;
        repeat (20) @(posedge clk1);
        $display("Test end");
        $finish;
    end

    always @(posedge clk2)
    begin
        if(clk1 == 0)   $display("Error1");
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk3)
    begin
        if(clk1 == 0)   $display("Error2");
    end
endmodule;
```

Comment: What do you think could be not deterministic?

Comment: Edited i.e Can it trigger error1 or error2?

Comment: the recommended way in generating of any clock is to never use non-blocking assignments there. NBAs in clock line will definitely cause data races and make behavior non-deterministic.

Comment: How do you divide a clock? As in `clk2`, using BA? If BA, what will synthesis infer it as?

Comment: Yes, use bas. Synthesizer does not care about ba/nba. This is only a simulation artifact. In general it will also not synthesize #delays and initial blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has problems, but nothing to do with determinism—it is fully deterministic. This is one case where using NBAs `<=` creates a problem. `clk2` gets updated in a *delta* cycle after `clk1` and `clk3`. That means if you have clock domain crossings from the latter to `clk2` like

```
always_ff @(posedge clk3)
   A <= B;
always_ff @(posedge clk2)
   C <= A; // A has already been updated with the value of B
```

So never use NBAs to make assignments to clocks.